# Compare data tems in a cart funtion

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to compare two attributes in the cart function?

```
   $data = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'price' => $price,
        'name' => $name,
        'stock' =>$quan
    );
```

So if I have to compare the qty and stock elements,how should I implement them at the controller?

Sorry for the late submission. Here is the controller code:

```
 function update_c() 
{ 
    $data = $_REQUEST;
    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items)
            {
                $name = $items['name'];
                $quantity = $items['qty'];
                $price = $items['price'];
                $sub = $items['subtotal'];
                $total = $this->cart->total();
                $id = $items['id'];     
                $quan=$items['stock'];
                if($items['quantity']<=$items['quan'])
                    {
                        $this->data['err_message'] = 'Your cart is added!';
                       $this->cart->update($data);
                        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $this->data['err_message'] = 'quantity mismatch';
                    }

            }             
}
```

Comment: can you post your current controller code?

Answer (score 0):

$data is the variable passed to your view from the controller so i am assuming you are already in the controller. If that's the case why don't you compare before putting them in the variable, but if that isn't the case a simple if statement with the array will suffice

```
if($data["qty"]==$data["stock"]){
   //Some statements
}
```

I hope i'm on the right course. Let me know what happens